# Copay does not go past splash page ios

Tags: copay, ios

I am running IOS 10.3 on an Iphone 6s and can't get past the copay splash screen no matter how long I wait.  Everything worked just fine until two software updates ago.

Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the duplicate of [copay does not work in iphone5 ios10](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73444/copay-does-not-work-in-iphone5-ios10)

Don't worry, it has been reported: https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/8382

It's not only you, other people seem to have the same problem.

Just wait until they release a fix for it.

**EDIT:** It has been fixed. Please update the app!