# Wallet copay does not function

Tags: wallet

I try to enter in my copay vallet and the screen turn white. What should I do I am from Argentina I try but I can make to function again. I try to formated the cell phone but it does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the duplicate of [copay does not work in iphone5 ios10](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73444/copay-does-not-work-in-iphone5-ios10) 
and [Copay does not go past splash page ios](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73600/copay-does-not-go-past-splash-page-ios/73617)

Don't worry, it has been reported: https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues/8382

It's not only you, other people seem to have the same problem.

Just wait until they release a fix for it.

Comment: @alvaraodeangelis It has been fixed! Just update the app.

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work

Comment: @alvarodeangelis Contact the developers via the github link above.

Comment: I dont understand what i Have to do